# add three std::vectors and store the result in the first vector

Tags: c++

I have three vectors, `vec1`, `vec2` and `vec3`.

I want to add all the three of them and store the result in vec1.

I am currently doing this,

```
std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), vec1.begin(), std::plus<double>());
std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec3.begin(), vec1.begin(), std::plus<double>());
```

I feel like I should be able to do it a bit faster than above, maybe in one transform. Any idea how to do it?

`vec1` is small. usually around 250 elements.

Comment: a loop that adds elements from the three vectors? Not everything must be slolved by standard algorithms, I don't know any that works on 3 ranges

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 maybe you are right. my vector is usually around 250 elements long. So I think it should be faster if I just loop through them.

Comment: @Morpheus, it's not like `std::transform` is not going to loop through your vector:)

Comment: number of elements doesn't matter. Standard algorithms aren't magic, `std::transform` does not more than running a loop and using the predicate to assign to the target range

Comment: `let vec3 = compose2 (+) <$> vec1 <*> vec2 <*> vec3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more efficient then 2 calls to `std::transform`:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec1.size(); ++i) {
   vec1[i] += vec2[i] + vec3[i];
}
```

You could write an algorithm for this, but there is none in the standard library that does it out-of-the box. You could use some weird predicate, but that would reduce readability rather than improving it.

Note that the main reason to use standard algorithms is not performance. If you look at their implementation you will realize that, all what is needed to make them generic aside, they are not different from a loop that you could write yourself. The main advantage of using them is expressivenes and readability. If there is no algorithm available to do what you need directly, abusing an algorithm gets you rather the opposite: unreadability and complicated code. The above is really more efficient than two calls to `std::transform`.